# Python OSError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, networking, subprocess

trying to create a test file to run two processes simultaneously. Using the subprocess module to do so. Having an issue where it says the file cannot be found, but it does not specify which file. We are using absolute filenames and can confirm that the path is correct. Can anyone tell us what this obscurity may be?

```
import subprocess
import random


port_num = random.randint(1049, 2000) # generates random port number
fns = open("filenames.txt").readlines() #reads in the file names
port_str = str(port_num)

for fn in fns:
    fn_nospace = fn.strip() #remove any excess spaces
    print fn_nospace
    cwdhalf = ['pwd']
    subprocess.call(cwdhalf)
    cmd1 = ['./webserver.py '+port_str] # open webserver with the input portnumber
    subprocess.check_call(cmd1) # calls cmd1
    cmd2 = ['wget localhost:'+port_str+'/'+fn_nospace] # samething with wget, only this time using the filename
    subprocess.check_call(cmd2)
```

The error being reported is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testwebserver.py", line 26, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(cmd1) # calls cmd1
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 493, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 480, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: both `call` and `check_call` wait for the corresponding child processes to finish. Use `Popen` if you want to run the processes in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback shows that the issue is with `cmd1`. Both commands in the code are incorrect.

The rule is simple: one list item -- one command-line parameter:

```
cmd1 = ['./webserver.py', port_str]
cmd2 = ['wget', 'localhost:%s/%s' % (port_str, fn_nospace)]
```

Also, OSError has `filename`, `filename2` attributes that you can inspect programmatically. [Though they are not set in this case](http://bugs.python.org/issue22536).